# Generate a sequential guid by myself

Tags: c#, ravendb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sequential Guid Generator C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752004/sequential-guid-generator-c-sharp)

I got documents which *might* be stored in raven. I'll like to generate a sequential GUID for them (I saw at RavenDB.net that raven uses them).

Are there a ravendb API that I can use to generate the id?

***Notice that the question is RavenDB specific***

Comment: GUID isn't sequential by definition.

Comment: @ChrisGessler: Not duplicate. I asked about ***RavenDb:s*** implementation

Comment: @jgauffin: do you want to generate on DB side, cause according to the [Ayende](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ravendb/5awuv842u38) post, it's enough to set `idColumn=null` ?

Comment: @Tigran: The documents might be stored. I want to generate the keys up front

Comment: @Dennis: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database

Comment: @jgauffin: don't believe, at this point,  that you have more choices then: 1. Simply look in the code 2. Write to Ayende and ask about this.

Comment: @Tigran: He or Matt Warren usually answers questions here too..

Comment: @jgauffin: entities, described in that article, are not **GUIDs**. They are looking **like** GUIDS, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below shows how RavenDB achieves this on the server for eTags, you can see it in context [here](https://github.com/mattwarren/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Database/DocumentDatabase.cs#L408). The other piece of the code is [here](https://github.com/mattwarren/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Database/Extensions/GuidExtensions.cs)

```
public Guid CreateSequentialUuid()
{
    var ticksAsBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(currentEtagBase);
    Array.Reverse(ticksAsBytes);
    var increment = Interlocked.Increment(ref sequentialUuidCounter);
    var currentAsBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(increment);
    Array.Reverse(currentAsBytes);
    var bytes = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(ticksAsBytes, 0, bytes, 0, ticksAsBytes.Length);
    Array.Copy(currentAsBytes, 0, bytes, 8, currentAsBytes.Length);
    return bytes.TransfromToGuidWithProperSorting();
}
```

I don't think this is accessible via the API as it's an internal detail, but you could implement something similar yourself. Basically it relies on having a global counter (`currentEtagBase` and `sequentialUuidCounter`).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if you're using GUID values, you wouldn't worry about them being *sequential*.

[`Guid.NewGuid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) will provide you with unique values you can use directly.

If you truly need sequential values, you can use the [Guid constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131157.aspx) which accepts integral types, and build sequentially increasing values.  This would be highly unusual, however.

Comment: Globally unique identifiers with a sequential part is nothing new. They exists for instance in SqlServer and speedup the lookup siginifically

Comment: @jgauffin Yes, but then they're typically auto-generated at insert.  Making new, sequential values manually isn't that common.

Comment: That's why I asked. I want to be able to use ravendbs implementation

Comment: Then check the code at github. Isn't it open source?

Comment: @jgauffin My understanding with Raven is that you just leave it as `Guid.Empty`, and when you call `Store`, Raven will give you a proper Guid.  You don't typically provide your own...

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Depends on what you want to do with the id..

Comment: @Peri: Do you always provide useful comments like that? gee, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not usual request: create a *sequential* `GUID`, as by definition, `GUID` is unique (as much as it possible) and presence of some mathematical, *predictable* sequence will introduce additional problems in its uniqueness support.

But, by the way, as usual, *there is always someone that think about this* already.

Seems that guy on this link had the same problem:

[Generate Sequential GUID](http://developmenttips.blogspot.it/2008/03/generate-sequential-guids-for-sql.html)

Note: the code provided is for `C# 2005`, but not much changed since that, in regard of this question at least.

**EDIT**

According to documentation, in regard of the sequential GUID generation:

> Numeric or Guid Id properties are supported and will work seamlessly.
>   In this case, RavenDB will automatically make the translation between
>   the inner string ID to the numeric or Guid value shown in the entity
>   and back.
>
> Using this approach, IDs are available immediately after calling Store
>   on the object - the RavenDB session will set a unique ID in memory
>   without asking one from the serve

That means even if it's generated by "server", its also stored in the memory, so ask for it will cost almost nothing, **if** this is your warry...