# In C#, would the return value of System.DateTime.Now.Ticks be affected by the switch between summer time and winter time?

Tags: c#, datetime

In C#, would the return value be affected by whether we're currently using summer time, if I check the time using System.DateTime.Now.Ticks, for example on a device in the U.S., and I don't change my local time zone at all?

Details:
For example I call System.DateTime.Now.Ticks periodically in an app. When the system time goes from summer time to non-summer time or vice versa, will the return value of .Ticks 'jump' (like for the length of 1 hour or -1 hours)?

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29489073/2441442). Use `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` instead.

Comment: What situation are you talking about? What does it mean for the return value to be "affected"? Can you explain using a code example? Your last sentence is incomplete: "if I check the time using..." *then what?*

Comment: No, it's not, The ticks is the internal value represents the date and time, however, if you use different Calendar or DateTimeKind, you may receive different ticks event other arguments are the same.

Comment: @Sweeper I added some detail in the question. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Why do you call DateTime.Now.Ticks periodically? What do you use the value for? If you want to measure some type of time *difference* you should probably use a stopwatch instead.

Answer (score 3):

It sure does. `.Ticks` returns a value appropriate for the `DateTimeKind` and doesn't do any corrections.

Note that calling `.ToUniversalTime().Ticks` won't work right for two hours a year due to the hour of fall back repeating itself; if you want your code to work, almost always call `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`; anything else is a pain.

Comment: So the return value of DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks will jump when the device switches from summer time to non-summer time and vice versa?

Comment: @GarfieldtheDummy It shouldn't jump, UTC doesn't have DST

Comment: @Martheen sorry I should have asked for DateTime.Now.Ticks

Comment: @GarfieldtheDummy Yeah, local DateTime will jump assuming the timezone has DST