# C# equivalent to SQL's NOW() function

Tags: c#

I've been looking around on Google, StackOverflow and many other sites but have failed to find an answer to this seemingly so simple question. In SQL you can use `NOW()` to generate a unique timestamp of right now, which wouldn't be repeated, example below.

```
0905b300-9baf-11e7-9257-cbc888cc9932
```

Its as simple as writing `NOW()` in SQL and CQL for that matter, but nobody has said anything about creating this type of string in C#? All I am able to create right now is horrible timestamps using the `DateTime` methods.

Comment: What are you trying to generate here, the UUID or the current timestamp?

Comment: I'm trying to find out the equivalent to SQL's `NOW()` function, and how to generate it inside of C#, not SQL.

Comment: `DateTime.Now`!

Comment: As I have clearly said in this question, DateTime.Now does NOT generate the string `NOW()` does.

Comment: I think this question is dead, it's clear to see nobody can be bothered to read the question before answering with useless answers that have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Can you share the documentation of your "NOW" function that seems to return a timestamp formated as GUID?

Comment: Now is not even a standard TSQL function. What system are you using. I agree with grant that I think you may have posted an incorrect result, or a formatted one ??

Comment: `NOW()` IS a valid function, I am using SQL on a MySQL database on Windows.

Comment: Based on the comments you have given it appears you are just looking for a sequential guid. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538870/80274) instead of the accepted answer on the linked duplicate on how to call `UuidCreateSequential` from the windows API which gives you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, you aren't actually using SQL, you are using CQL, or the Cassandra query language. Cassandra has a quirk that it uses the GUID type to store date and time values; as such, this type is known in Cassandra as [timeuuid](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html).

In C# there is no such thing. For date-time values there is a DateTime type, and for unique identifier values there is a Guid type. You shouldn't use one for the other. There is no built-in way to convert between the two, either.

Neither does any variant of SQL that I know of re-use the GUID type in this way.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [Guid.NewGuid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) which generates a unique identifier:

```
// This code example demonstrates the Guid.NewGuid() method.using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Guid g;
        // Create and display the value of two GUIDs.
        g = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine(g);
        Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}


/*
This code example produces the following results:

0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e
7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7

*/
```

Comment: This is a GUID, not a timestamp of any kind and therefor can't be used as a timestamp.

Comment: Subsequent calls to this are not guaranteed to produce sequential guids.

Comment: Agreed, Mike's accepted answer is better

Answer (score 3):

Use `Guid.NewGuid()`.

```
using System;

public class MyClass
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        var guid=Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine(guid.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a GUID, not a timestamp of any kind and therefor can't be used as a timestamp.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using? (E.g. Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate the output from SQL Server's `NOW()` function, you can use `DateTime.Now`, but change the output to match what `NOW()` actually returns using `ToString` with an appropriate format mask.

```
DateTime nowDate = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + nowDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + ".");
```

**Output:**

```
Today is 2017-09-17 16:19:46.
```

## Demo

Answer (score -1):

In C#, use [System.DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx).

NOTE. NOW() function is not SQL it is proprietary MySQL . The function it provides is to generate a time-sequential (constantly incrementing) value. In short, a value that can be used to sort events chronologically. This function, in C# is provided by the property `DateTime.Now`, which also conveniently happens to contain the actual date and time.  If you have to have a sequential guid, then use [UuidCreateSequential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: As I have clearly said in this question, DateTime.Now does NOT generate the string NOW() does.