# Insert using a Sequence as generator for a Primary Key value in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, tsql-sequence

I have a sequence that looks like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.NextWidgetId
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH 100
 INCREMENT BY 2
 NO CACHE 
GO
```

And a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Widget_Sequenced]
(
    [WidgetId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.NextWidgetId),
    [WidgetCost] [money] NOT NULL,
    [WidgetName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [WidgetCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastChangedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RowVersionId] [timestamp] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Widget_Sequenced] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WidgetId] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Is there a way to add a new record to this table structure using Entity Framework?

I tried setting `StoreGeneratedPattern` for `WidgetId` to `computed` and I tried it with `Identity`. Both gave me errors.

I tried this with EF 5. But I could move to EF 6 if it fixes this.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible from version 6.2, using this code:

`System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UseScopeIdentity = false;`

More information on [EF6 does not work with primary key from sequence](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/165)

Comment: Where does one set this value? and what attribute is needed on the field that represents the SEQUENCE column?

Comment: @jkerak [ef6.2-issue165.cs](https://gist.github.com/divega/31a15d492283ab34e6631ab6686f6705#file-ef6-2-issue165-cs)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your sequence with IDENTITY(100, 2) and everything will work out of the box.

Comment: Well, it is avoiding the problem, rather than solving it. Yes, `IDENTITY(100, 2)` will work similar to this particular `SEQUENCE`, except there is no `NO CACHE` option for `IDENTITY`, as far as I know. Besides, this `SEQUENCE` object may be used in other tables to generate single sequence across several tables - you can't easily replicate this behavior using `IDENTITY`.

Comment: As far as I know, `NOCACHE` option is used to mitigate gaps in indexes. However [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) says "Gaps can still occur if numbers are requested using the NEXT VALUE FOR".

Comment: Thanks. I had an identity and am moving to a sequence. I need to be able to update the value (to make it move partitions).