# Adding guid default value constraint to sql primary key not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, constraints, guid

I have an empty table that has two column  : Id and Title .

The Id is `guid` type , `Primary key` , so `Not Nullable` .

I try to add a  `constraint` for default value of Id  ,  constraint is like this :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TestTable_Id]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [Id]
GO
```

In Entity Framework , Because Id is not nullable , It fill the Id with `'00000000-0000-0000-000000000000'`  value .

Therefor  my constraint in sql doesn't work property  for creating new `sequentialId()` and my first record in table get `'00000000-0000-0000-000000000000'` value. 
And it's so obvious for the second row it get the:

`"Vaiolation of PRIMARY KEY Constraint "PK_TestTable". Cannot insert Duplicate Key"` error .

I know I could generate guid in .NeT like `Guid.NewGuid()` and fill the Id with value , But I'm trying to delegate this responsibility to sql and `newsequentialId()` default value .

I'm wonder how could I do that  ?

For full info i put the entire script here  :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TestTable_Id]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [Id]
GO
```

**Update**: My EF database first approach Mapping is:

```
public partial class TestTable 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenereatedOption.Computed)]
    public System.Guid Id {get ;set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set NewId() for GUID in entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200817/how-to-set-newid-for-guid-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map your property Id as Computed like this:

```
Property(o => o.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

OR

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

OR, if you have edmx you must edit property in designer:
[image: property mapping]

Comment: Thanks for the Idea , But I try it , and it didn't work , Still the same error

Comment: I Update the code , Because I use the Database First Approach  I don't have Mapping code, Just putting attribute on my model .

Comment: @Mostafa you have edmx, and you should update Id property in designer, I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for the idea , I changed the StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity  (it's not by default ) and worked (I don't know why), Please correct your answer so I could accept your answer .

Comment: @Mostafa it's primary key, of couse. I edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some requirement to do this the hard way:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TestTable_Id] 
    DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [Id]
```

`NEWID()` is the `TSQL` equivalent of `GUID.NewGuid()`