# NEWID() SQL Server Function in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am developing a web application using **AngularJS**, **ASP.NET**, **Entity Framework** and a **SQL Server** database.

I want to insert some rows using **EF** with this method :

```
public string addRow(int CaptionID, string enLang)
{
    string output = "";
    try
    {
        var Cap = new Table_Name();

        string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        Cap.CodeId = CaptionID;
        Cap.Created = DateTime.Now;
        Cap.CreatedBy = userName;
        Cap.ID = "";
        Cap.CodeLanguage = "en";
        Cap.CodeCountry = "GB";
        Cap.Caption = enLang;
        _db.Entry(Cap).State = EntityState.Added;

        _db.SaveChanges();

        output = "Created";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        output = ex.InnerException.Message;
    }
    return output;
}
```

This function works.

But I have a question about the `NEWID()` function, I have searched a lot to know how to reproduce the same but I didn't knew, I've looked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200817/how-to-set-newid-for-guid-in-entity-framework) but nothing.

In fact, I want to assign `NEWID()` to `Cap.ID`.

**P.S** : I know that is it possible to do it using SQLServer by assigning an `SELECT NEWID()` to `Cap.ID`, but I am looking for a way to do it using **EF**.

Comment: [C# how to create a Guid value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344098/c-sharp-how-to-create-a-guid-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do: `Cap.ID = Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: I didn't taught it was as simple as that, thanks a lot ! :-)

Comment: @aBennouna No problem. And if `Cap.ID` is a `string` (which it shouldn't be) you need to add a `.ToString()`

Comment: Yes I've added it @Magnus

Answer (score 2):

If you want that EF do the job for you you can do this in your `Table_Name` entity using [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#DatabaseGenerated):

```
public class Table_Name
{
  [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public Guid ID {get;set;}
  //...
}
```

This way you can define your `ID` column as [Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column), and when you add new element and save changes, the database will generate the `ID` for you.